# Runtime Error after handling 400

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

**Scenario:**

The username and password is authenticated using WebApi 2 token authentication. If the credentials are correct, then token is returned. But, if the credentials are incorrect, 400 bad request is returned. In my Ionic 2 project, if I get the response, I navigate to the next page. If I get the error, I show my custom error message.

**Issue:**

The issue I'm facing is, if I enter the wrong credentials for the first time, the custom error message is shown. If I enter wrong credentials again, the custom error message is shown along with the ionic error message.

**Here is my code:**

login.ts

```
  doLogin() {
    if (this.Username !== undefined && this.Password !== undefined) {
      this.loading.present();
      this.authSrv.login(this.Username, this.Password).subscribe(data => {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
        this.loading.dismiss();
      }, (err) => {
        this.errorMsg("Invalid Username/Password !" + err);
        this.loading.dismiss();
      });
    }
    else
      this.errorMsg("Please enter Username/Password");
  }
```

auth-service.ts

```
  login(username, password) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    urlSearchParams.append('username', username);
    urlSearchParams.append('password', password);
    urlSearchParams.append('grant_type', 'password');
    let body = urlSearchParams.toString()
    return this.http.post('http://' + this._api + '/postoken', body, { headers: headers }
    )
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map((res) => {
        if (res !== null) {
          localStorage.setItem('acess_token', res["access_token"]);
          localStorage.setItem('access_type', res["access_type"]);
          localStorage.setItem('expires_in', res["expires_in"]);
          this.loggedIn = true;
        }
        return res;
      });
  }
```

**Screencast:**

[image]

**Error**

[image]

Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[LoadingController](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) can only be called once.

> Note that after the component is dismissed, it will not be usable anymore and another one must be created.

This is causing the exception.
You should create new loading everytime in `doLogin`.

```
doLogin() {
    if (this.Username !== undefined && this.Password !== undefined) {
      this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({ //create here
    content: 'Please wait...'
     });
      this.loading.present();
      this.authSrv.login(this.Username, this.Password).subscribe(data => {
        this.navCtrl.setRoot('HomePage');
        this.loading.dismiss();
      }, (err) => {
        this.errorMsg("Invalid Username/Password !" + err);
        this.loading.dismiss();
      });
    }
    else
      this.errorMsg("Please enter Username/Password");
  }
```

Comment: Hey @suraj, how did you know that the problem was in `Loading` from the given code in the question? Just not getting it. Because he has not created the loading there and doing multiple logins on the same page? Is that it?

Comment: `doLogin` is presumably called on button click and `this.loading` is not reset.. had seen the problem with it before... after `this.loading` is dismissed on first click, it is not created again before the second click