# Separate component for Loader :Error: Uncaught (in promise): false

Tags: angular, ionic2, loader

I have create a loading component to show and hide loader.
it work fine on the login page and home page,bus as soon as i call it again from another page it gives the error

I want to create a separate component for loading and not repeat the code in every page

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): false

Below is the code of the loading.modal.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';


/**
 * Generated class for the LoadingModal component.
 *
 * See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentMetadata-class.html
 * for more info on Angular Components.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'loading-modal',
  templateUrl: 'loading-modal.html',
  providers:[]
})
export class LoadingModal {

  text: string;
  loader: any;

  constructor( public loadingCtrl: LoadingController ) {
    this.text = 'Hello World';
    this.loader=this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
    });
  }

  showModal()
  {
    this.loader.present();
  }

  hideModal()
  {
    //alert("hide modal");
    this.loader.dismiss().catch(() => {});
  }

}
```

From the home page when the next page is pushed then in the constructor of the new page i try to show the loader again

```
/**
 * Generated class for the ProductCatalog page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-product-catalog',
  templateUrl: 'product-catalog.html',
})
export class ProductCatalog {

public currentCatId:any;
public productArray=[];
public imageBaseUrl:string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public prdServ: ProductService,public appService:AppService, public loaderService: LoadingModal) {


      this.imageBaseUrl=appService.ThumbNailUrl
      this.currentCatId=navParams.get("catId");
      loaderService.showModal();
      prdServ.getProductsforCategory(this.currentCatId).subscribe(data => {

            this.productArray=data.items;
         loaderService.hideModal();      

        });
  }

  loadDescription(product){
  var p=product;

  this.navCtrl.push(ProductDescription,{product:p});

  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
  }

}
```

Below is the ionic Info:

```
Cordova CLI: 7.0.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v7.4.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

I have read a lot of threads where people have the same issue but not able to figure out how to solve this.

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319612/runtime-error-after-handling-400/43319729#43319729

Comment: Don't create overlay components in services or providers, instead create them as they are required, from within component class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So taking clue from the comment as per the [Doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/loading/LoadingController/)

> Note that after the component is dismissed, it will not be usable
>   anymore and another one must be created. This can be avoided by
>   wrapping the creation and presentation of the component in a reusable
>   function as shown in the usage section below.

Loading component once dismissed cannot be used again.
i.e we have to create a new loader everytime we wish to use it.
So in my **loading.modal.ts** i moved the create method to the **showModal** method.
So now everytime showModal is called a new loader is created and is available for use.

```
export class LoadingModal {

  text: string;
  loader: any;

  constructor( public loadingCtrl: LoadingController ) {
    this.text = 'Hello World';

  }

  showModal()
  {
    this.loader=this.loadingCtrl.create({
    content: 'Please wait...'
    });
    this.loader.present();
  }

  hideModal()
  {
    //alert("hide modal");
    this.loader.dismiss().catch(() => {});
  }

}
```